# How to convert html to pdf and make it attached to email on Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce, dompdf

I'm using Wordpress and WooCommerce and I need to ensure that attached to my "New Order" email is all the content of the email (texts and images) in pdf format.

With the following code I managed to have the content of the email in pdf using Dompdf library but the images are missing. I have the error message "Image not found or type unknown" and I have lots of visual errors:

- Some, very small parts of the email are found on an entire page of the pdf on their own
- Some texts have disappeared (these are mostly parts of texts that come from shortcodes that I made to get some info on my orders in the mail.
- Some texts have been moved, for example text found in a table is, once in pdf, outside the table, the table is therefore empty.

How can I make sure that the mail keeps all the style it had before and that the images are displayed correctly?

```
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
function htmlToPdf($html, $outputFile) {
    
    $dompdf = new Dompdf();

    $dompdf->setBasePath('/wp-content/uploads/');
   
    $dompdf->loadHtml($html);

    $dompdf->render();

   
    file_put_contents($outputFile, $dompdf->output());
}

function ajouter_contenu_en_piece_jointe($phpmailer) {
    
    if (strpos($phpmailer->Subject, 'New Order') !== false) {
        
        $body = $phpmailer->Body;

        $filename = 'New_order_' . time() . '.pdf';
        
        htmlToPdf($body, $filename);

        $phpmailer->AddAttachment($filename);
    }
}
add_action('phpmailer_init', 'ajouter_contenu_en_piece_jointe');
```